# Importing CSV to QGIS but doesn't work properly

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv

I'm trying to import CSV to QGIS but have a problem with coordinates. I added CSV (with longitude and latitude) via add delimited text-layer.
[image]

Then I added OpenStreetMap and arrange the CRS

[image]

But it looks like this! Points are not even on the map. I tried to open OSM then import CSV. Checked the CRS and lon-lat numbers over and over but nothing changed. Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

[image]

I was using 3.16.11 but yesterday downloaded 3.22 and still have the problem.

---

I tried all the answers and I also tried another CSV file downloaded from youtube but it also doesn't work on maps (OSM and Google Maps) as the data provider imported it on his QGIS map. So I think there is a problem with my CRS settings on QGIS. I did WGS 84 EPSG:4326 for project properties and also for layer properties but I don't know what's wrong with them.

Comment: can you check your .csv with a text editor and check the decimal-seperator of your coordinates?

Comment: It seems the `COO-X` and `COO-Y` are swapped. Change the header of `COO-X` to be `COO-Y` and `COO-Y` to be `COO-X`, and try again.

Comment: Try to swap your coordinates when importing the CSV

Comment: I was using 3.16.11 but yesterday downloaded 3.22 and still have the problem

Comment: Could you share your data, if it is not classified?

Comment: Thanks, solved. When I fixed the CSV data on text editor and not change CRS value of the map, it worked finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me in your description as if you are changing the CRS value of your openstreetmap data set. That should just be left as it is from the provider. You set the CRS on the project and then the data sets you are using are projected to the project CRS. Also as @ahmadhanb said, watch out for lat,lon and X,Y, It is a quite common mistake (been there, done it) to mix it up, since cooordinates given as lat,lon are Y,X (first north-south, then east-west)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `COO-X` and `COO-Y` are swapped. Change the header of `COO-X` to be `COO-Y` and `COO-Y` to be `COO-X`, and try again

Here is the correct location from your CSV:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I fixed the CSV data on text editor and not change CRS value of the map, it worked finally. I think I just need to solve converting Excel file to csv.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Glad to hear, but  this would better have been added as a comment to your original question.